# Magento unsecure URLs set to https > can't access to admin and front

Tags: magento-1.9, url, ssl, https

I am using Magento version 1.9.1

I have installed ssl certificates and given the base secure url as https://www.mydomain.com. I have also selected both the options : Use secure urls in frontend and Use Secure urls in admin.

But it didn't worked, so I've tried to set the unsecure urls to https and I've saved it.

Now I am not able to access into my admin page or My site ..

Before I reinstall magento and start from scratch, are there any other ideas that I should be trying?
THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your database and the table core_config_data:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'
```

Change the values back to the old domain (without https).

Then flush the Magento cache.

Afterwards you should be able to access your store again.

Answer (score 0):

another quick way would be to restore your last backup database (supposing you are backing up your database, which you should do to ensure any corrupted info can be restored).

Rob